# Analysis of peaks in MATLAB mesh plot

Tags: matlab, image-processing, 3d, signal-processing, gaussian

I am carrying out curvature analysis on the image below and need to be able to measure the distance between peaks. Please can someone shed some light on how this is done? I am only interested in the positive portion of the graph and it would useful if the height of each peak could also be extracted.

I have tried using findpeaks but it asks for a vector and I do not have one to give it.

I am using the surfature function from the online Mathworks repository. For the purpose of this question, 'X' is my input image into the Gaussian filter:

```
    G = fspecial('gaussian',[19 19],6);
    X = imfilter(X,G,'same');

    [XI YI]=meshgrid(1:size(X,2), 1:size(X,1)); % Just create the x and y
    [K, H, P1, P2, C, SI]=surfature(XI, YI, X);

    figure(2);

    mesh(surfature(XI, YI, X)); colormap gray;
```

I would be very grateful for any help.

[image: curve_image1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic behind `findpeaks` for 1D arrays / vectors is that it looks at local 3 element neighbourhoods and sees whether the centre of the window is the maximum element.  If it is, this could potentially be a peak.  You would also need to apply a threshold to ensure that you don't get noisy low amplitude peaks.  In 2D it's quite straight forward.  Look at a 3 x 3 pixel neighbourhood (or it could be any size you want) and see if the resulting maximum is the same as the centre location of each neighbourhood.  You would increase the size of the neighbourhood to analyze if you have very noisy data.  Increasing the size of the neighbourhood filters out more noise, but at the expense of potentially losing valid strong peaks that are near each other.  This you will unfortunately have to play with in order to get it right for your application.

Because you tagged this post as image processing, I would recommend you look at this in an image processing view point.  Specifically, look at morphological dilation with [`imdilate`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imdilate.html).  Dilation is equivalent to a maximum filter, and so what you could do is do something like this.  I'm not sure whether you're using `K`, `H`, `P1` or `P2`, so modify accordingly:

```
thresh = 0.01;
sur = H; %// or K, P1, P2
sur(isnan(sur)) = 0; %// Set any NaN values to zero
N = 3;
se = strel('square', N);
out = imdilate(sur, se);

pks = out == sur & sur > thresh;
```

`pks` would be a 2D array that is the same size as the mean curvature stored in `H`.  We also only want to look at the positive peaks, so we also need to check if `H > thresh`.  `thresh` is a threshold to be sure that we don't look at low amplitude peaks.  I don't know which one you want to use, so I'll leave that up to you.  Once you have the locations of where the peaks occurred, you can use `pks` to index into `H` or whatever you want to determine what the actual peaks are:

```
pks_val = sur(pks);
```

If you want the actual `X`, `Y` and `Z` locations for the peaks, you can do:

```
xvals = XI(pks);
yvals = YI(pks);
zvals = X(pks);
```

`XI` and `YI` I'm assuming is some meshgrid of points (going by your variable names), while `X` is an image and you can find where in the image the peaks also correspond to.

Now, for your question on the distance between peaks, this is very ambiguous as you have 2 degrees of freedom.  Supposing you have this image:

```
0 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 1 1 1 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 1 0 0
```

If we did a peak detection, any values that have `1` would be classified as a peak.  If you want to find the distance between peaks... ok... in which direction?  For example, looking at the centre most position, which single distance value would you use to assign the distance between any of the other peaks to the centre?  Would you use the one to the left? right? top? bottom?  You have two degrees of freedom and are trying to quantify something into a single value, and so there will certainly be ambiguities.

My suggestion is to rethink what you're trying to actually do with these peaks and do something else other than measuring distances between peaks.

Comment: Thank you for your time with this answer, it's really helpful. Allow me to explain a bit more...

The peaks represent the positions and height of a backbone in an animal. I am attempting to measure the properties of this backbone such as vertebrae spacing, etc. This was the best way I could come up with of extracting the data from my images. If you have a better solution I would be very grateful to hear it. The work above is the result of 4 months of research and testing so I would welcome any fresh ideas.

Comment: I get the following erros when trying H, K, P1 or P2:

Error using imdilate
Expected input number 1, IM, to be non-NaN.
Error in images.internal.morphop>ParseInputs (line 125)
validateattributes(A, {'numeric' 'logical'}, ...
Error in images.internal.morphop (line 21)
[A,se,pre_pad,...
Error in imdilate (line 120)
B = images.internal.morphop(A,se,'dilate',mfilename,varargin{:});
Error in cis_v2_0 (line 128)
out = imdilate(sur, se);

Comment: Aha. Filter out the NaN values with isnan. More soon on my way to work.

Comment: Edited my post.  Was a simple edit.  You simply search for any NaN values and set them to zero.  If there is a general direction where the vertebrae are appearing, you could perhaps use a Hough Transform and follow along the line to determine the distance from one peak to the next.  In 1D it's pretty simple... you would just search to the left or right, and report the closest distance.  In 2D, there are a lot more directions you would need to search... specifically a full 360 degree circle.  I'll have to think about that and get back to you, but the above edit should work to get your peaks.

Comment: That seems to have done the trick with regards to the error, thank you. I am still not getting much useable data though. What I need is to be able to return the location in x,y,z of the peaks and store it to an array, that would be really useful! Thanks again for your time.